# Como mudar de Activity ao clicar em uma opção no menu AlertDialog?

Tags: java, android

Estou com o seguinte problema, tenho um metodo que é chamado, quando a pessoa clicar em um botão, E SEGURAR, (onLongClickListener) aparecerá um alert com várias opções.
1º Opção é Cancelar a Mesa, 2º Ver pedidos, e 3º Chamar outra activity.
Acontece, que dá erro quando eu clico na terceira opção, onde estaria o meu Intent, chamando outra Activity.

Obs: 
A inicialização da outra activity nao tem erro, pois eu consigo acessar ela por outros botões usando o mesmo método Intent intent = new Intent();

```
private AlertDialog opcoes;
CharSequence op[] = new CharSequence[] {"Cancelar Mesa", "Ver Pedidos", "Acrescentar/Alterar Pedido", "Teste"};
private void opcoesMesas(final View v) {
    //Cria o gerador do AlertDialog
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    // define o titulo
    builder.setTitle("Escolha a Opção desejada: ");
    //define a mensagem
    //builder.setMessage("Deseja cancelar essa mesa?");
    //define um botão como positivo
    builder.setItems(op, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                switch(i){
                    case 0:
                        ConfirmacaoDeCancelamento(v);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        exibindoPedidosDasMesas(v);
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        openPedidos();
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        break;

                    default:
                }


        }
    });
    builder.show();
}


private void openPedidos(){
    startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(),pedidos.class));
}
```

No case 2:, eu já tentei colocar o Intent direto, também nao dá.
E ele reconhece que foi clicado na terceira opção, pois eu ja coloquei um Toat para me informar caso chegasse no Case 2, e deu certo.

Me ajudem, eu so preciso chamar outra tela, ao clicar no Case 2.

Comment: Poste o *logcat* com o erro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes de ir para a próxima `activity` chame o método `dismiss()` do dialog e então chame o método `openPedidos()`

Comment: o que faz, pra que serve esse, dismiss() ?

Comment: fecha o  dialog. chame-o : dialogInterface.dismiss(); ou dialogInterface.getDialog().dismiss();